# What's the origine of this quote?

Tags: spinoza

This is a popular Spinoza quote
"Nothing in Nature is random...A thing appears random only through the incompleteness of our knowledge." Spinoza, Ethics I.
Yet, it is not in Ethics.
Can anyone help me trace the origin of this quote?

Answer (score 6):

Spinoza, [Ethics](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Ethics_(Spinoza)/Part_1), Part 1:

> **Prop. XXIX**. Nothing in the universe is contingent, but all things are conditioned to exist and operate in a particular manner by the necessity of the divine nature. [*Latin*: In rerum natura nullum datur contingens sed omnia ex necessitate divinæ naturæ determinata sunt ad certo modo existendum et operandum.]

And *Note* to **Prop. XXXIII**.:

> a thing can in no respect be called contingent, save in relation to the imperfection of our knowledge. [*Latin*: At res aliqua nulla alia de causa contingens dicitur nisi respectu defectus nostræ cognitionis.]

Comment: Current Cambridge translation: "[T]he only reason 
why a thing is said to be contingent is owing to a failure in our cognition." (Prop. 33 Scholium I)

Comment: Thank you very much. Sometime in the past, the "Nothing in Nature is random" version took off as a free translation, but surely it must refer to Prop. 33.

Comment: @BalazsAczel If this answers your question, you can accept it by clicking at the tick on the upper left side of the post.